# second getline or other input functions doesnt work when i exceed the array size in input for first getline()

Tags: c++, getline

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
char d,a[9],e[9];

cin.getline(a,9);
cin.getline(e,9);
cin>>d;
puts(a);
puts(e);
cout<<d<<endl;
return 0}
```

when i enter "hey every one" on the output screen, `puts(e)` prints a blank line and d prints a random character.second `getline` function and `cin`function is not working because of first `getline`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, stop this `#include <string.h>` and `#include<stdio.h>` nonsense, this is not C++. If your tutorial teaches you that, get a better one.

Comment: so what should i use instead of these..what do u recommend... please mention ..thanx in advance

Comment: The corresponding C++ headers would be `<cstdio>` and `<cstring>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) for the stuff you use:

> After constructing and checking the sentry object, extracts characters from *this and stores them in successive locations of the array whose first element is pointed to by s, until any of the following occurs (tested in the order shown):
>     - [...]
>     - count-1 characters have been extracted (**in which case setstate(failbit) is executed**).

(Emphasize mine)

So the first `getline` fails if the input is too long and thus leaves `std::cin` in a bad (i.e. unreadable) state. This makes all successive input operations fail immediately.

---

Remark: To avoid tons of ugly trouble, you should avoid using C-style strings and the "kind of C-style" member-`getline` and just use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and the non-member [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Comment: thanx .i understood. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use

> cin.getline();

and when you press Enter after entering the string, that enter goes into the next string.

> In order to prevent it, use 
>   cin.ignore();

It ignores the Enter and prevents it from entering into another string.

Here is your modified code:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
char d,a[9],e[9];
cout<<"String:"<<endl;
cin.getline(a,9);
cin.ignore();
cout<<"String:"<<endl;
cin.getline(e,9);

cin>>d;
cout<<a;
cout<<e;
cout<<d<<endl;
return 0;
}
```